# Какой API для захвата видео с камеры использует Skype?

Tags: winapi, видео, камера, skype

Моё Windows-приложение для запуска требует наличие вебкамеры. Один из пользователей не может с ним работать, так как на его ноутбуке не определяется вебкамера... точнее, драйвер находит, и лампочка загорается, но при съёмке чёрные квадраты. Приложение на C++ - пробовал захват средствами OpenCV с перебором всех кодеков и разрешений его камеры - чёрные квадраты... Приложение vmcap (стандартная примочка для камер) пишет, что не удалось открыть граф (похоже работает через DirectShow)... И я бы посоветовал ему перебить винду если бы не одно но - Skype как-то удаётся завести эту старую камеру и получать нормальные кадры вместо чёрных квадратов. **Как он это делает, через какое API???**